# Centering two divs side by side, but one div has a fixed position

Tags: css

I have a container with 2 divs that I wanted to appear side by side, centered on the page. The left side would be a navigation of sorts, and the right side would have variable length content. I wanted the left div to be "fixed" as I scroll up and down the page. 
Here's a general structure; feel free to suggest other centering css. 
Thanks in advance.

```
#content{
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#left{
  display:inline-block;
}
#right{
  display:inline-block;
}

<div id="content">
  <div id="left">
  </div>
  <div id="right">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but have not tried anything yet.. its only `divs`

Comment: There's no good place to tell you this coddee (you don't have any visible email address or other way of contacting you), so I apologize for putting it here, but I knew this would produce a notification for you. You tried to make an edit on a question with the comment "Not an edit, but a request to unhold this question". That's not the proper venue for such a request. Such requests should be made on meta, instead: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ . The question you made this edit on can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252380/rstudio-shiny-zingchart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a bit short to answer properly, but i'd say:

```
#content {
     text-align:center;
}
#left,#right{
     display:inline-block;
}
#left {
     width:200px;
}
#left > div.fixed {
     position:fixed;
     width:inherit;
}
```

If you had some real life code to use and make fit to your needs, it will help you.

The child of #left is going to b the container for your fixed content. #left, in the flow will keep the room needed.

Comment: Sorry about the vagueness. That is exactly what I needed though. Thanks!